# change color in shaded environment

Tags: color, framed, backgrounds

I'd like to switch color in a shaded environment (package framed.sty). Something like that :

```
\definecolor{shadecolor}{1 0 0}
\begin{shaded}
This line is red

\switch{yellow} and this line is yellow

Back to red !
\end{shaded}
```

or an environmented version :

```
\begin{shaded}
This line is red

\begin{switch}
and this line in yellow
\end{switch}

Back to red !
\end{shaded}
```

I tried to change the `\FrameCommand` in the definition of the `\switch` macro but it doesn't work (I don't exactly understand when the `\FrameCommand` is called).

Ideally, I'd like to stick with the framed package, but if another is more suitable, I'll go for it!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the [framed](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) package and the manual is not so revealing. As I could not get your code snippets to compile I recommend using [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), which is a much more powerful package for this sort of thing - another option that you could consider is [mdframed](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed).

I am not entirely sure what effect you want, but using nested `tcolorbox` environments with the default settings, except for background colour, gives:

[image]

With a little more effort you can remove the indentation, the frames and the rounded corners:

[image]

The [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) manual is very comprehensive and readable.

Here is the full code for the images above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

  Standard nested boxes using tcolorbox:

  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!]
  This line is red

  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!]
  and this line in yellow
  \end{tcolorbox}

  Back to red !
  \end{tcolorbox}

  With a little more effect we can remove frames etc:

  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!,boxrule=0mm,sharp corners]
  This line is red

  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!, boxrule=0mm,
     grow to left by=5mm,
     grow to right by=5mm,
     sharp corners]
  and this line in yellow
  \end{tcolorbox}

  Back to red !
  \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to be the way to go, and wanted to give ot a try yesterday. My MikTeX being a little out-of-date, I made an update to get the latest version in the package manager.
Unfortunately, I can't compile anything since...